# How to show a tooptip to the select box

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have a select box inside the form.

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label>![enter image description here][1] :
    </label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select required name="gender" id="gender" class="span12">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="M">Male</option>
            <option value="F">Female</option>
            <option value="U">Unknown</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want that when the user clicks the form submit button if no option is choosen than a tooltiip to display in the left side of the select box.The i want the tooltip pointer should point to the middle of the select box.

How i can achieve this?
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by tooltip upon click? usually tooltip is showed when hovering, and there is a different response mechanism for click events. Can you provide some code and screenshots to clarify the question?

Comment: @Ray'user1578904' he means he wants form validation messages to show as a tooltip

Comment: Is this is a ASP.NET for or JSP..., And where do u going to check the validation backend or frontend. Because the solution depends on the way u validate above condition. Also if you are using ASP.NET required field validator agin the solution will differ...

Comment: I am using jsp and i wantr to do it on clientside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tagged Bootstrap, you can achieve **`tooltip`** using **`Bootstrap's JS Components`**.

I have tried a simple one,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select").tooltip({
        placement: 'right'
    });
});
```

Sample [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ytpAy/74/).

Hope you got some idea.

Comment: Yes this is what i was looking for. But could you please tell me how to execute this tooltip javascript on click form submit button